# Computing MD5SUM of large files in C#

Tags: c#, md5, hash, large-files

I am using following code to compute MD5SUM of a file -

```
byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);
string sum = BitConverter.ToString(new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(b));
```

This works fine normally, but if I encounter a large file (~1GB) - e.g. an iso image or a DVD VOB file - I get an Out of Memory exception.

Though, I am able to compute the MD5SUM in cygwin for the same file in about 10secs.

Please suggest how can I get this to work for big files in my program.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I suggest using the alternate method:

```
MD5CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(Stream)
```

and just pass in an input stream opened on your file.  This method will almost certainly *not* read in the whole file in memory in one go.

I would also note that in most implementations of MD5 it's possible to add `byte[]` data into the digest function a chunk at a time, and then ask for the hash at the end.

Comment: Yep.  Mono in fact implements ComputeHash(Stream) by iteratively reading into a byte[4096] (http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/HashAlgorithm.cs?revision=107126&view=markup).  I would expect that MS's implementation is very similar.

Generally, using ReadAllBytes probably means you're doing something wrong.  Even for short files, using a Stream is more elegant.

Comment: This is pretty sweet.  I tried simple solutions from other posts about reading to a memorystream, etc, but they all seemed to fail for extremely large files.  This works perfectly and it's super simple.  Thanks :)